# MacBook Pro battery cycles keep increasing though plugged in continuously

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power

I keep my MacBook Pro 16" plugged in all the time. My cycle counter keeps going up one by one every few days.

Perhaps one of my apps is forcing lots of power consumption? Is there an application that monitors which app is draining the battery most?

Comment: Do you have an external monitor connected to your MacBook Pro?

Comment: No but I tend to have USB devices plugged in. And they can cause problems. Right?

Comment: What is the exact version of macOS Catalina that you have installed? Do you have Battery health management enable?

Comment: 10.15.6 and yes it's enabled